# How to use ruby libraries in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed a ruby gem

```
 gem install anemone
```

But I cannot hit off to use it directly in my rails application, this is the first time I'm using an external ruby library so it will be very helpful if you can give me an insight into it rather than just a solution

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

In your `Gemfile` add:

`gem 'anemone'`

This way Rails will load the library when it starts, and you can then use it. You don't even have to use the `require` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You must put used libraries into  Gemfile.  Everything about gemfiles is available on [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) page.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [official Rails guide about this topic](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#dependencies-and-config-gem).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use 'require' and the name of the library on top of the file where you want to use the library. For example if you are using nokogiri you would need to add the line `require 'nokogiri'`

Comment: I get the following error                                                 MissingSourceFile in ExtractorController#index

no such file to load -- anemone